# how to get an array to reference a class

Tags: java, arrays, class

I wish to try to make an array reference a class but can not think of a way to do this.
I have my main class, client and another called organisation.

Im basically making a small database where the user is able to add an organisation and also edit the info in the organisation. Info including, ID#, name, address, ect

I d like to know how i can get an array to basically store new organisation class's so that when i want to add an organisation it runs a new organisation class and stores that version of the class, in the array.

Comment: Is `Class<?>[]` what you're looking for?

Comment: What is this? Please Explain :D

Comment: `Class<?>` is a reflection type for a Java class. The `<?>` means "any class" using the generic type syntax.

Comment: Is it not appropriate to just have an array of organisations: `Organisation[]`?

Comment: Of course, you should not be storing `Class`es in a database.

Comment: @DuncanJones in which case I'm overthinking it :-(

Answer (score 2):

You may be best using a `List`, unless you can be sure of the maximum number of organisations that can be associated with a client. The size of an array is fixed at the point it is created, which may not be appropriate for your use case.

For example:

```
public class Client {
  private final List<Organisation> organisations = new ArrayList<Organisation>();

  void addOrganisation() {
    // dummy/example method
    organisations.add(new Organisation("Foo", new Address("blah")));
  }
}

public class Organisation {
  private final String name;
  private final Address address;

  public Organisation(String name, Address address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<Organisation>`

is the best option I think. read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to get familiar with it. it's quiet handy.